# Webdriver findelements does not pick up inner html

Tags: webdriver

I am trying to use the following code to extract the inner html of menu items but it only picks up the text that is in the same line for some reason. Here is the code:

```
            WebElement ReportStart=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Reports')]"));
            List<WebElement> reports= ReportStart.findElements(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'menu_')]"));
            System.out.println(reports.size());

            for (int i = 0; i < reports.size(); i++) {

                System.out.println(reports.get(i).getAttribute("id"));
                System.out.println(reports.get(i).getText());

            }
```

It picks up all the id's but only the inner text of some of them and not nested one. So it picks up text **Reports** and **id menu_1035** and **menu_1036** but **not the text General** as it is not on the same line. Not sure why this is that findelements does not pick the whole web element

```
<li>
<a id="menu_1035" class="dynmenu" href="#">Reports</a>
 <ul>
  <li>
   <a id="menu_1036" href="#">
    General   
   <span class="dwn"/>
   </a>
 <ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Are these element visible on the screen ? getText() method retrieves innerHTML of elements that are visible, see this link: https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getText%28%29

Answer (score 0):

Its not picking the text `General` as it is inner-html of `li` tag not `a` tag.

Your `xpath` only fetches element which has `id` - `//*[starts-with(@id, 'menu_')]`

If you want to get `General` text also, then you need to update your `xpath' that points only till`li` element.

Hope it helps.